# Can I use ref.current.setState(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a situation that want to call a `Child.method` from `Parent`, though this is not a best practice, but I just want to give it a try. And I decide to use `ref.current.setState()` in the `Parent` component.

Here is the example code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/8lmvq3yq68

There are some unexpected behavior happened where `ref`, `setState` and `react-router-dom` are used together. When I use `Redirect` and `ref` together, the `Child.componentDidUpdate` will not be called. I wonder if it is a valid code in `React`? Since I can not find any doc that showing it is invalid. Or is it a bug of `react-router-dom`?

Comment: You don't need a ref to do that, just any old object. But if you are going to use a ref I believe if you want to pass up methods, the way to do that is with `forwardRef` on the child component

Comment: In your example, you could just pass `name` as a prop into `Superhero` and avoid the whole ref complexity. Is there a reason this is not feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged in some additional component lifecycle logs to clarify.
So what's happening is when you select the 'Link' to '/' There are 2 parallel calls that will fire.

1. Navigate to the '/' route
2. The onClick event

So one will first navigate to the relevant route while the other will trigger the ref's function. You will see the "Calling the state change" log.

> What happens when you route to the '/' path is that the **SuperHero
>   component is unmounted!** And you will see the "Unmounting - Superhero"
>   log. So the state change is lost and componentDidUpdate will not be fired. Nevertheless, as you can see, the redirect does happen
>   and the component is mounted again. Now it has no sense of the state
>   change but the "Mounting - Superhero" will be logged.

I have further included a separate button. Since there is no unmounting, this works as you expect!

https://codesandbox.io/s/81v0mz0548

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.superheroElement = React.createRef();
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.superheroElement.current.changeName();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Link to={"/"} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          haha
        </Link>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} render={() => <Redirect to="/post" />} />
        <Route
          path="/post"
          render={props => <Superhero ref={this.superheroElement} {...props} />}
        />
        <br/>
        <button  onClick={this.handleClick}>
          haha
        </button>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

class Superhero extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Batman"
    };
    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
  }

  changeName() {
    console.log("Calling the state change");
    this.setState({
      name: "Bruce Wayne"
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // Not called because component is unmounted
    console.log("Updating - Superhero");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Mounting - Superhero");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("Unmounting - Superhero");
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.name}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```